# open <Select> onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Вообщем, есть елемент `<select>`  и нужно по нажатию кнопки его открыть.

Как это сделать?

HTML:

```
<select id="selector">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option> </option>
</select>
<button> Open select </button>
```

Вообщем, как привести `select` к открытию при нажатии кнопки? Зная, что `.click()` не работает в этом случае.

P.S. Вот [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chil7/dfab2n0h/3/) c примером

Comment: Все очень просто. Никак :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно по клику измменять size селекта
http://htmlbook.ru/html/select/size

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  openSelect('button', '#selector')
})

const openSelect = (triggerSelector, selectSelector) => {
  const trigger = document.querySelector(triggerSelector) // Достаем нужные елементы
  const select = document.querySelector(selectSelector)
  let selectSize = select.options.length // сохраняем первоначальное количество елементов в селекте
  trigger.addEventListener('click', () => {
    select.focus()
    select.size = selectSize //по клику выставляем высоту селекта
  })

  select.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    select.size = 1 // тут сбрасываем обратно
  })
}
```

```html
<select id="selector">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
  <option>5</option>
  <option>6</option>
</select>
<button> Open select </button>
```

Comment: Cпасибо за код, но я так понял что сделать именно так не получится как я хотел?

Comment: к сожалению, нет.

Comment: спасибо и за это!